# Memory leak in Java. How to clear list?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jvm

I have found some list in my source code which has `list.add()` but not `list.remove()`. Is it causing a memory leak? I tried `list.clear()` and `list=null` but it seems to have no effect.
What should be done to clear this list? Kindly explain... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Code please... is it from the Java Collection Classes?

Comment: How did you found out that there is memory leak? How did you check that 'list.clear()' or 'list=null' have no effect?

Comment: Then cause of leak might be different

Comment: please explain how you know the memory leak is from list... Please use some profiling tool to find out the real culprit. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools#Java try jprofiler it was useful when i tried it

Comment: @ntalbs i used mat that is showing leak suspect as one of the classes which implements a listener for handling indications. I checked memory usage from jvm console with and without list.clear() have almost same value.

Comment: @Nilamber You already know that GC will not performed immediately after you do 'list.clear()' or 'list=null'. GC has its own schedule to perform and you can monitor gc with jvisualvm graphically, which is distributed with JDK. Perhaps you can see the memory usage go down if you wait for a while.

Comment: @ntalbs Do you mean to say if we run garbage collector from jvm console by pressing g,There is no guarantee that gc is performed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list.clear()` will clear all the reference from the list. If they are not used by any other objects it will be cleared from memory by `garbage collector`. But `clear` alone will not `delete` the objects. I think the problem is, some other objects are using the data so it is still there in the memory.

Post sample code to make us know what is the exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clear a list you can just call `List.removeAll`. Until objects are referenced somewhere they are not eligible to be garbage collected, so if a `List.removeAll` does no effect, it means that the object that were in the list are still referenced somewhere else, for example in another collection or class.

How do you know that `List.clear`/`List.removeAll` makes no effect ? It is not mandatory to remove each element that were added to a list manually. It is possible that a list runs out of scope and so is discarded.

```
{ 
    Foo a = new Foo(1.0);
    Foo b = new Foo(2.0);
    {
        List<Foo> foo = new ArrayList<Foo>();
        foo.add(a); foo.add(b);
    } // scope ends for foo, remove was not called but still
      // the list is discarded, and the reference it holds to a and b too
}
```

So, to clear the list, just call `List.removeAll`. If you want the objects that were in the list to be garbage collected, you have to make sure that they are no more referenced anywhere.

Comment: { Foo a = new Foo(1.0); Foo b = new Foo(2.0); { List<Foo> foo = new ArrayList<Foo>(); foo.add(a); foo.add(b); } list.removeAll();}  Will work if foo is not used after this?